# Вывести данные из массива, внутри друго массива

Tags: php, массивы, foreach, вывод

Вывел на экран массив, кодом:

```
                $item_list = file_get_contents("items_game.json");
                $inv = json_decode($item_list, true);


                print_r($inv['items_game']['loot_lists']);
```

И получил данные вида:

```
Array
(
    [all_drops] => Array
        (
            [Acid Hydra] => 1
            [Adornments of Blight Set] => 1
            [Agaric Flourish] => 1
        )
      [all_single_drops] => Array
        (
            [Zaru'Kina Protector's Cape] => 1
            [Zaru'Kina Protector's Hair] => 1
            [Zaru'Kina Protector's Pads] => 1
        )
      [arcana_drops] => Array
        (
            [Blades of Voth Domosh] => 1
            [Demon Eater] => 1
        )

       [artificers_chisel_2015] => Array
        (
            [Artificer's Chisel - Single Use] => 1
        )
```

Как можно получить данные сразу со всех массивов ? А точнее первый стобец (ключики) от всех массивов ? Без единичек, просто слова, которые заключены в квадратные скобки внутри каждого массива.
Всё что сам осилил, это вывести названия каждого массива. Понимаю что я близко, но знаний не хватает. Вот код которым я вывожу названия массивов:

```
           foreach ($inv['items_game']['loot_lists'] as $key => $value) {
                echo $key."</br>"; //all_drops, all_single_drops, etc...
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите вывести названия *Zaru'Kina Protector's Cape, Adornments of Blight Set*, то тогда, все просто, Вам нужен внутренний цикл для перебора внутренних массивов.

```
$list = $inv['items_game']['loot_lists'];

foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $innerKey => $innerValue) {
              echo $innerKey;
        }
    }
}

//или вот так, тогда все ключи будут в allKeys

$allKeys = [];

foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $allKeys = array_merge($allKeys, array_keys($value));
    }
}

var_dump($allKeys);
```